# Basic HTML5/Canvas Setup. Browser issues

Tags: html, canvas

I have this basic HTML5/Canvas setup. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, I am having these browser issues:

- If I load the page about ten times in IE8, it will typically work at
  least once... I know this sounds strange; I can only guess it has
  something to do with the order the JavaScript is being executed(?).
- The text does not appear in my iTouch.

Edit: I am having some formatting issues with this code.  Excanvas is used (but not seen below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>      


<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">     

    function addBox(x, y, text){
        context.font = '17px Arial';  

        context.textBaseline = 'top';  
        context.fillStyle      = 'black';
        context.fillText  (text, x, y);
    }

    function resetCanvas(){ 
        c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
        context=c.getContext("2d");

        c.width = 450;
        context=c.getContext("2d");

        //Draw Picture Frame around Canvas
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle="blue";     
        context.strokeRect(5,3,430,430);    
    }   

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        resetCanvas();
        addBox(200, 200,'hello');
    });     
</script>      


</head>      
<body>     

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="450" >Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

- IE8 doesn't support canvas, so whatever you're seeing it's not a canvas issue
- Are you sure your iTouch has the Arial font available?  What happens if you try `sans-serif` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I should mention that the formatting here on Stack Overflow prevented me from displaying this line:  <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->  I have seen a similar ssetup work with the excanvas.js.   Regarding the 'arial' tip, I am going to look into it. Thanks.